# How to add several colors to list?

Tags: c#, colors

I have this list:

```
List<System.Windows.Media.Color> colorsList;
```

And here I want to add several colors into my list:

```
public void FillColorsList()
{
    colorsList = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>();
    colorsList.Add(System.Windows.Media.Color.)
}
```

And after `System.Windows.Media.Color.` I cannot see all the colors table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [`Colors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx) class not the [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color(v=vs.110).aspx) struct which contains the predefined colors:

```
colorsList.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.AliceBlue);
colorsList.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.AntiqueWhite);
// ...
```